# Isolate MySQL code from bootstrap in PHPUnit (Lumen)

Tags: php, phpunit, lumen

I have the following PHPUnit configuration:

```
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="bootstrap/app.php"

</phpunit>
```

However, inside the `bootstrap/app.php`, another file is included (`routes.php`) where I'm making an SQL query. So, I was wondering how I can refactor this code so I can avoid running SQL during the bootstrap of phpunit? `bootstrap/app.php` is required to be run to set everything up for the Lumen framework.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add a condition in your `routes.php` file:

```
if (!app()->environment('testing')) {
    // SQL query goes here.
}
```

Hope I understood your question, sorry if not.